# Recover user certificates from old domain profile

Tags: windows, active-directory, certificate

I have had problems with my Windows 2008 server domain, so I have reinstalled the whole server and recreated the user profiles, but I forgot to extract the user digital sign certificates. Now, the old domain is not available and the computer have been changed to the new domain, so I cannot login to export the certificates. Is there anyway I can recover the user certificates from the old profile?

Thank you very much for your help.

Best regards

Comment: If you didn't delete the old user profile you could try disconnecting the computer from the network and logging into the old profile using the following user name format: **OldDomainName\OldUserName**. If you're able to successfully log in then you might be able to export what you need.

Comment: The computer has been removed from the old domain, and its now in the new one. Is possible to login in the old domain?

Comment: It might be if you specify the username in the format I specified in my first comment. Disconnect the machine from the network and give it a try.

Comment: Hi! I have try it. With network disconnected it says that there no domain server available. With network connected it says that the password is not recognized. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Everything below assumes that the old domain still exists on at least 1 DC, or that you have a backup of one of the DC's that can be restored to provide temporary functionality, even if nothing is connected to it at this time, if that is not the case then I can't think of a way to recover the certs and it's probably best to issue new ones which you'll probably need to do this for most of them anyway to deal with a new domain name.

2 options if the old domain still exists somewhere would be to either move the machines back to the old domain temporarily, export the certs, and then move the machine back into the old domain.  Second option would be to create a trust relationship between your new and old domains and then grant members of the old domain login rights on your workstations, then export the certs.

Hope that helps, let me know if you need me to clarify anything.